# cacosf (Complex arc cos) function in C returns indefinite

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, complex-numbers

I have an algorithm coded in MATLAB, which contains complex arc cos of some value (computation requires arccos of 15, which is approximately 3.4i). I want to code C or C++ counterpart of this code running on my Windows 7 PC. Actually, I want to produce it as a mex function compiled with Visual Studio C++.

I included "complex.h" and used cacosf function (complex arccos returning float _Complex) but I could not compile it as a mex function because Visual C++ compiler **does not** have "complex.h" support. However, mex file can take libraries as input, so I can compile my c code with another compiler that MATLAB does support (for example mingw, I integrated it to matlab with **gnumex** utility.) I downloaded Bloodshed C++ IDE which uses mingw at backend, I can compile my c++ code. The following C++ code represents a similar operation to my goal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main() {
    float _Complex myComplex;
    myComplex = cacosf(5);
    printf("Complex number result of acos(5) is : %f + %fi \r\n",crealf(myComplex),cimagf(myComplex));
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

> > Complex number result of acos(5) is : 0.000000 + -2.292432i

However I get

> > Complex number result of acos(5) is : -1.#IND00, -0.000000

When I compile my C++ code with Linux GCC on Ubuntu 14.04 computer with Eclipse CDT Luna I get

The output should be:

> > Complex number result of acos(5) is : 0.000000 + -2.292432i 
> >     Where can I be wrong? Why can't I compile this code in Windows + mingw setup?

Note: I can compute cacosf(0) as 1.570796 + -0.000000 when I use mingw.

Answer (score 0):

What version of `mingwrt` are you using? With `mingwrt-3.21.1`, the following works for me, (cross-compiling on a Linux host, and running under `wine`):

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main()
{
  double _Complex Z = cacos(5.0);
  printf( "arcos(5) = (%g, %gi)\n", __real__ Z, __imag__ Z );
  return 0;
}

$ mingw32-gcc -o foo.exe foo.c

$ ./foo.exe
arcos(5) = (0, -2.29243i)
```

This seems to be consistent with your expected result. However, if you use *any* `mingwrt` version pre-dating `mingwrt-3.21`, (and the less said about utterly broken `mingwrt-4.x` the better), then there is a known bug resulting from arbitrarily deeming any purely real `cacos()` argument value greater than `(1.0, 0.0i)` to be outside the valid domain, (as would be the case for `acos()` on its real part), which would yield the result you report.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++, as the name says, is a C++ compiler. C++ uses the `<complex>` header and `std::complex<float>` type. Since C++ has overloading, you can call [`std::acos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/acos)   for complex values too.

Your code is in fact C, which is no longer supported by MSVC++. (They stopped doing that back in 1996 or so)